# Cannot delete connection definition 'It has associated connection'

Tags: multithreading, delphi, database-connection, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

My code has a design time `TFDConnection`. Parameters are set up, it is opened, and I then derive a ConnectionDefinition from it to be used later (concurrently):

```
lParams.Assign(AConnection.Params);  (TStringList)
l := lParams.IndexOfName('Pooled');
if l <> -1 then
   lParams.Values['Pooled'] := 'true'
else
   lParams.Add('Pooled=true');
lConnName := AConnection.ConnectionName + 'Pooled';
if FDManager.IsConnectionDef(lConnName) then
   FDManager.DeleteConnectionDef(lConnName);
FDManager.AddConnectionDef(lConnName,AConnection.DriverName,lParams);
```

I have a type `TTSQLScript`:

```
TTTSQLScripts = class(TComponent)
private
  FConn: TFDConnection;
  FScript: String;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; AConnection: TFDConnection); reintroduce;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  function Execute : Boolean;
  property Script : String read FScript write FScript;
end;
```

with

```
constructor TTTSQLScripts.Create(AOwner: TComponent; AConnection: TFDConnection);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FConn := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  // Pick up the pooled connection definition for concurrency:
  FConn.ConnectionDefName := AConnection.ConnectionName + 'Pooled';
  FConn.ResourceOptions.ParamExpand := false; 
  FScripts := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TTTSQLScripts.Destroy;
begin
  FConn.Close;
  FreeAndNil(FScripts);
  FreeAndNil(FConn);
  inherited;
end;

function TTTSQLScripts.Execute: Boolean;
begin
   try
      FConn.ExecSQL(FScript);
      Result := true;
   except
      Result := false;
   end;
end;
```

After opening the design time connection, I use the `TTTSQLScripts` component:

```
lTTSQLScripts := TTTSQLScripts.Create(Application,ADataConnection);
lTTSQLScripts.Scripts.Text := 'some SQL';
lTTSQLScripts.Execute;
FreeAndNil(LTTSQLScripts);
```

**Issue**:

When I set up my design time `TFDConnection` for a second time, after code like the above has run, the `FDManager.DeleteConnectionDef` call triggers a:

> [FireDac][Stan][Def]-251 Cannot definition [xxxPooled]. It has associated connection.

So something is holding on to a connection, but I can't see what.

**Is there something incorrect or suspicious in the above construction** that would cause this?,
or: **Can I find out anything about the connections that are still 'associated' when I try to delete the definition?**.

All `AConnection` variables passed around refer to my design time `TFDConnection`.

Added:
I also tried changing the definition connection properties, but this fails with the same error once the TTTScripts has run:

```
var lDefCon: IFDStanConnectionDef;
lDefCon := FDManager.ConnectionDefs.ConnectionDefByName(cPooledName);
lDefCon.Params.Assign(lParams);
lDefCon.Apply;
```

Comment: I never had the need to delete a connection def. Either I reuse it when it matches or I create a new one. It is my understanding that pooled connection instances are kept when unused and not destroyed. Thus the referenced connection def has to be available, too. I also don't understand, why you create a connection def from an existing connection. Why not create the connection def in the first place and make use of that all over the place?

Comment: As for that last question: history and unfamiliarity. There was an old design time TSDDatabase component that I replaced with a TFDConnection. When converting an existing app you don't want to break too much open at once (like replacing all those threads with parallel TTasks). But I'll look into your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Closing FDManager before setting up the new connection appeared to be the easiest solution.

It's obvious that this will work because the pooled connection is removed as well.

(This means I have not gone to the bottom of the issue, but I need to go on with production code; there's a limit I'm willing to spend on tinkering. Therefore I will not mark this answer as *the* solution).